# Почему не получается сделать адаптивку?

Tags: css, stylus

Я использую вот такой код

```css
.focus-form{
  width: 24%;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.91);
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-right: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  h4:first-child{
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p{
    font-size: 21px;
    span{
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1455px){
  .focus-form{
    width: 40%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
  .focus-form{
    width: 79%;
  }
}
```

Но почему-то он не применяется, то есть применяется стандартный `.focus-form` и `media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1455px)` а дальше уже не применяется `media screen and (max-width: 320px)`
Как тут быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример работает, но попробуйте переместить `@media (max-width: 320px)` .

```css
.focus-form{
  width: 24%;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.91);
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-right: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  h4:first-child{
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p{
    font-size: 21px;
    span{
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
  .focus-form{
    width: 79%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1455px){
  .focus-form{
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="focus-form">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Interactively empower worldwide experiences vis-a-vis best-of-breed action.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Но почему-то так у меня не рабоатет